# Geth --fast -rpc snycing issue

Tags: wallets

I am using the ethereum wallet on xubuntu 17.04. I have been using geth --fast --rpc to sync since geth --light will not connect to peers. I got this error for geth --fast --rpc [syncing](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/o4GwDB7KW5KPTRuXYZ4qzw)

Comment: Hi there. Your log dumps seem to have been removed (the links are dead). Did you find the problem in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try running Geth with the next command:

`geth --fast --cache=1024 --rpc --verbosity=6`

With verbosity you could get every log and if show you an error would be more detailed.
[dump](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/cFnxvSlvlpfoYkPk~P5uMA)

Comment: I am having difficulties piping it to a text file but I did my best in copying the output to [pastebin](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/NA4gvn8F53hoasyIlRVSXA)

Comment: [More detail dump](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/cFnxvSlvlpfoYkPk~P5uMA)